# Send a file to Telegram with Julia

Tags: julia, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm writing a Telegram bot in Julia and I can't figure out how to send files correctly.

I've seen similar questions for other languages but it wasn't helpful.

Currently, I have such function:

```
function sendDoc(chat, fileName::String)
    file = open(fileName)
    url = string(base_url, "sendDocument")
    mp = HTTP.Multipart(basename(fileName), file)
    query = Dict("chat_id" => chat)
    HTTP.post(url; query=query, files=Dict("document" => mp))

    close(file)
end
```

I try it on a simple `test.txt` file with the content `abc` so the size of a file or it's name can't be a reason for any errors.

What I get from it (and also in case if I use `file` instead of `mp`) is an HTTP 400 error (I removed some parts for privacy purposes):

```
ERROR: LoadError: HTTP.ExceptionRequest.StatusError(400, "POST", "/bot/sendDocument?chat_id=", HTTP.Messages.Response(v"1.1.0", 400, Pair{SubString{String},SubString{String}}["Server" => "nginx/1.16.1", "Date" => "Thu, 12 Mar 2020 GMT", "Content-Type" => "application/json", "Content-Length" => "94", "Connection" => "keep-alive", "Strict-Transport-Security" => "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" => "*", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" => "Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Connection"], UInt8[0x7b, 0x22, 0x6f, 0x6b, 0x22, 0x3a, 0x66, 0x61, 0x6c, 0x73  …  0x20, 0x72, 0x65, 0x71, 0x75, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74, 0x22, 0x7d], HTTP.Messages.Request("POST", "/bot/sendDocument?chat_id=", v"1.1.0", Pair{SubString{String},SubString{String}}["Host" => "api.telegram.org", "User-Agent" => "HTTP.jl/1.3.1", "Content-Length" => "0"], UInt8[], HTTP.Messages.Response(#= circular reference @-2 =#), 1, nothing)))
```

I also tried putting `mp` or `file` in `body` instead of `files` but then I get the following:

```
┌ Info: Error in @async writebody task. Server likely closed the connection unexpectedly. Only an issue if unable to read the response and this error gets re-thrown. 
│   exception =
│    MethodError: no method matching write(::HTTP.Streams.Stream{HTTP.Messages.Response,HTTP.ConnectionPool.Transaction{MbedTLS.SSLContext}}, ::Pair{String,IOStream})
│    Closest candidates are:
│      write(::IO, ::Any) at io.jl:582
│      write(::IO, ::Any, ::Any...) at io.jl:584
│      write(::IO, ::Complex) at complex.jl:217
```

Including the file in `query` is also something I could try but then it would be in the URL and I'd be very limited in file size.

The 400 error looks the same as if it would be missing a field, so I assume that Telegram can't see the `Dict("document" => mp)`, but at the same time error includes `UInt8[0x7b, …  0x7d]` which looks like the contents of the file. How do I make it right?

Comment: The second error here actually occurs in a case matching [the intended use of HTTP.Multipart](https://github.com/JuliaWeb/HTTP.jl/blob/master/src/multipart.jl#L96). Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, it's not `HTTP.Multipart` that I needed, it's `HTTP.Form`.

The following function works:

```
function sendDoc(chat, fileName::String)
    url = string(base_url, "sendDocument")
    file = open(fileName)
    query = Dict("chat_id" => chat)
    HTTP.post(url, query=query; body=HTTP.Form(Dict("document" => file)))

    close(file)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to, you may use [Telegram.jl](https://github.com/Arkoniak/Telegram.jl) package, which in particular includes support for document and images sending.

You can do it like this

```
using Telegram, Telegram.API
tg = TelegramClient(bot_token; chat_id = chat)

open("picture.png", "r") do io
  sendPhoto(photo = io)
end
```

Here `bot_token` and `chat` are bot token and chat id.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a photo in your directory "Foto.jpg". To send a photo, you would need this:

```
fileName = "Foto.jpg"
url_photo = string("https://api.telegram.org/bot",bot_token,"/sendPhoto")
file = open(fileName)
query = Dict("chat_id" => bot_manu)
HTTP.post(url_photo, query=query; body=HTTP.Form(Dict("photo" => file)))
close(file)
```

Where 'bot_manu' should be your chat id, 'bot_token' is the bot id token. Hope this helps for those who wanted to send a photo. To get 'bot_manu' and 'bot_token' I used BotFather.